# Printing Space Between Strings

Tags: bash, shell, printf

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY="185.18.207.66 31.18.212.113"

result=""

for i in $ARRAY
do  
    result=$(printf '%s %s' "$result" "$i" "checked")
done

paste <(printf "%s\n" $result)
```

I am trying to print IP addresses but with appending `"checked"` phrase for each IP address.

But I can not print a space between IP and `"checked"` phrase

Above code prints:

```
185.18.207.66checked
31.18.212.113checked
```

How can I make it to print like below?

```
185.18.207.66 checked
31.18.212.113 checked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to improve with your script before making it done right:

- Missing double quote
- Spawning unnecessary external commands.

---

Just using an array instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=(185.18.207.66 31.18.212.113)
printf '%s checked\n' "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

or using `"$@"` to make it POSIXly:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- 185.18.207.66 31.18.212.113

printf '%s checked\n' "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need to read access_log and iterate over the IPs. So I just used a simple "for" loop as an example. Would you mind showing me the way I provided please? I know your way looks better but my current script requires this way.

Comment: @NecNecco: You can save to an array variable for each IP then print them all after finish reading the log. And why don't you just print it out immediately when you got and IP?

Comment: I use `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` for access_log. So I gather the IP list, than checking if the IP is blocklisted in IPtables. If it is already banned, I removed it from the list. After iterating all, I print out only the IPs that are not banned.

Comment: So just do `set -f; ARRAY=( $(<your_command_here) ); set +f` then use `for ip in "${ARRAY[@]}"`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I just omitted the result variable and used printf simply in the for loop. Is there any culprit using printf multiple times in a bash script?

Comment: @NecNecco: `printf` is a bash builtin, so you should you it when possible.